# How to print the HTML content of the text field in Drupal 6 programmatically

Tags: entities, 6

I am printing the `$node->field_abc[0]['value']` in php code where node is node content and `field_abc` is text field .

How can I print the html format of the field in Drupal 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[content_view_field](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!cck!content.module/function/content_view_field/6)**

> content_view_field : Render a single field, fully themed with label
>   and multiple values.

Code

```
$node = node_load('NODE_ID');
echo content_view_field(content_fields("field_example"), $node, FALSE, FALSE);
```

Reference

- [Print a formatted CCK field with PHP](http://www.trevorsimonton.com/blog/cck-field-render-node-formatter-format-output-print-echo)

Comment: Just one case How can I prevent the label field in the display of the field??